# Data occurrence in openModeller?

Tags: modelling, model

I am having problems adding occurrence data to [openModeller](http://openmodeller.sourceforge.net/) and I think that the format might be the problem.

I am using Excel with the fields: #ID Taxon Name Longitude Latitude.

I saved the result on a .txt format but openModeller won't detect it.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to clarify whether you are using oM Desktop 1.1 or the openModeller plug-in to QGIS, please?  http://openmodeller.sourceforge.net/om_desktop.html